# Convert Dif (data interchange format) To any readable format.CSV EXCEL

Tags: javascript, php

```
**Hello**
```

I would like to know if there is any way to convert Dif file into any other common file formats such as CSV Or EXCEL or any file that i can work with. If it possible it would be greate if it will be in php but js is also good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the excellent [XLSX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) library in JavaScript for this purpose, for example in Node.js to parse to CSV and Excel (.xlsx) format:

```
const fs = require("fs");

const XLSX = require('xlsx');
const workbook = XLSX.readFile('test.dif');

const firstSheet = workbook.SheetNames[0];
const csv = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(workbook.Sheets[firstSheet]);

console.log("CSV output:", csv);
fs.writeFileSync("csv_output.csv", csv, "utf8");

// Write to excel format.
XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'out.xlsx');
```

You can use similar code to parse in-browser, though you may not have access to the local file system.

Comment: I'm sorry but i need this in php